# python smtplib , Problems when try to send email with python script

Tags: python, smtplib

i want to send an email automatic with pyhton. This is my Code:

```
#send email
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.ionos.de', 465)
try:
name="Mein Name" #You need to fill the name here
server.connect('smtp.ionos.de', 465)
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login("[info@test.de](mailto:info@test.de)","Passwort")
TOADDR = "[test@web.de](mailto:test@web.de)"
FromADDR = "[info@test.de](mailto:info@test.de)"
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Testbetreff"
msg['From'] = FromADDR
msg['To'] = TOADDR
#The below is email body
html = """\
<html>
<body>
<p><span style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">Dear {0},</span></p>
<p>
your email body
</p>
<p>Kind Regards,<br />
Your name ....
</p>
</body>
</html>
""".format(name.split()[0])
msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html'))
server.sendmail(FromADDR, TOADDR, msg.as_string())
except Exception as e:
# Print any error messages to stdout
print(e)
finally:
server.quit()
```

i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:\Users\MeinName\Downloads\emailsendenTest3.py”, line 5, in
server = smtplib.SMTP(‘smtp.ionos.de’, 465)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File “C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\smtplib.py”, line 255, in init
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File “C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\smtplib.py”, line 343, in connect
(code, msg) = self.getreply()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File “C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\smtplib.py”, line 405, in getreply
raise SMTPServerDisconnected(“Connection unexpectedly closed”)
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: Please also read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you understand how to post code with proper formatting, as indentation is crucial in Python, and [edit] the post to fix it properly. Aside from that: in your own words, why do you believe it should be possible for your program to connect to `smtp.ionos.de` on port 465? What if the people who own that mail server don't want you to?